# Stalker which is killing women

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

I'd like to know the title of the movie. There are not much I remember about it. But, I'll try my best.

- I watched it around 2010. So the movie maybe around 2000-2008.
- It is in English
- Its genre maybe horror/thriller
- The stalker seems attracted to women. But not sexually attracted. He seems to adore them (As I recall, there are no rape scenes).
- His first victim is strangled/smothered to death
- I think his job is a chemist. He is working with potions / solutions. He has a mentor
- There's a scene in which he is embalming a woman (covered the woman with some sticky stuff)

I'll add some when I remember more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're talking about [**Perfume: Story of a murderer**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0396171/). It's about a young man, with a really strong smell sense. It's actually based on a Novel.

From Wikipedia:

> The film tells the story of Jean-Baptiste Grenouille (Whishaw), an olfactory genius, and his homicidal quest for the perfect scent.

- I watched it around 2010. So the movie maybe around 2000-2008. **(This movie was released in December 2005 in the US.)**
- It is in English. **(It's a German/French/Spanish movie but its language is English.)**
- Its genre maybe horror/thriller **(More like a thriller, not a horror)**.
- The stalker seems attracted to women. **(He is attracted by the woman's scent, so he stalks them.)**
- His first victim is strangled/smothered to death **(Suffocates first victim)**.
- I think his job is a chemist. **(He becomes a perfume maker apprentice, thus working with potions and stuff.)**
- There's a scene in which he is embalming a woman, [Here You go](http://photos1.blogger.com/x/blogger/6041/2199/1600/892291/DasParfum-34.jpg).

I will leave some screenshots to see if you can recognize it.
[image: This is the Killer]

[image]

Comment: Just remember to mark it as a correct answer if it did help. Best regards!!

Comment: I haven't check the movie / trailer. The screenshoot is quite ring a bell. Can you tell me why it fits my description?

Comment: @Vahn check my edit